# Tab before numbered list items in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to write a document using a template with a variety of styles.  When I look at the template with formatting marks visible, the numbered list looks like this:

[image]

When I try to create new lists in a document built on this template, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

It is not aligned the same as other numbered lists in the same style.  If I hit tab on a list item, it won't create the initial arrows, regardless of whether I have selected the "set left- and first indent with tabs and backspaces" option.

If I use "alt + shift + right arrow" on an entry of the second list, it shifts right and *appears* to have the correct alignment.  But I'm not sure, and I'm suspicious since there aren't formatting arrows visible to the left of the roman numerals like there are in the original template list.

My questions:  what are those initial arrows in the original list?  Can I do something to a new list to format it identically?  Does "alt + shift + right arrow" have the same effect, even though I don't see the initial arrows in the formatting view?

I am using Microsoft Office 2016 with Windows 10.

Comment: most probably the initial "list" is not a list, just plain text formatted to look like list.

Comment: I believe that's it.  Ugh.  I'm going to tell the people who supply the template to add text telling users to turn off automatic numbered lists when using it.